# Synonyms to "running joke"

Tags: phrase-request, synonyms

Is there a synonym to the phrase "running joke" in any context? I feel like I've heard something like *onrunning* and I'm not sure if there isn't a connotation of an *inside joke*, that could serve as a synonym.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "synonym"? Different word, same meaning? Well, then, **running gag** is another way to say *running joke*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_gag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **A running joke**

is a thematic piece of recited humour which continuously recurs over time.

> **An inside joke**

is one that is understood only by people "in the know", but may not recur.

You may be thinking of

> **An on-going joke**

which is a piece of recited humour that continues across an entire story line.

Whereas

> **an ongoing gag**

is more a vignette than a recited joke.

Comment: Interesting analysis. However, I don't think that a running joke has to be "recited" or "thematic." I've worked in offices that had running jokes. See the definition in [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/running-joke): _something that a group of people continue to refer to and find funny over a period of time_.

Comment: Thx. So does someone say just an "inside"?

Comment: No, the term is **inside joke** the people who understand the joke are **insiders**.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between a ***joke*** and a ***running joke*** is that running jokes occur over a span of time – sometimes for days or weeks, sometimes for months or years. They aren't simply told once and everyone moves on. In fact, people often find them funny largely because they remember the last time people referred to the joke.

The difference between a ***joke*** and an ***inside joke*** is that inside jokes are only funny to people who have certain background information that allows them to understand (and therefore be amused by) the joke.

The two are not the same thing, but there can be overlap, in that an inside joke can also become a running joke when it recurs over a long span of time.

For example, let's say we had an aunt named Henrietta who liked to take care of stray cats. It started with one cat in 2002, then she found two more two years later, and five years after that she took in a fourth kitten. We may adore and respect Henrietta, but, because she has taken in four cats, perhaps we still like to joke around and call her a "crazy cat lady." Maybe, every year during the holidays, we ask, "Is the crazy cat lady coming over, too?" Maybe three first three cats have all died and she only has one cat now, but we still call her the "crazy cat lady" because that's the running joke.

This could be considered a **running joke** because we've been calling her the crazy cat lady for several years now. But it might also be considered an **inside joke** if not many people outside of her immediate family knows about her love for cats. If I went into her workplace, for example, and asked, "Is the crazy cat lady here?" I might get a puzzled look from the receptionist because Henrietta's coworkers are not aware of the longstanding running joke in the family.

Answer (score 0):

When a person is a **running joke**, they've come to be regarded as a fool. Nearly everything they do reinforces this view of them. It's one idiocy after another. Hence "running", as a TV series can be "running" -- episode after episode  being aired.  When a situation is a running joke, the people who have created it and are perpetuating it are seen as fools. They are not "ha-ha" funny but objects of ongoing ridicule.

An **inside joke** is one that only a small group of people would understand because it has special private meaning.